# How to create a pair of all common elements in a list and return False if there is no pair of common elements

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and trying to solve the below problem but i am not geeting the output that i am expecting, so please hlep.

I want to create a pair of all same elements in a List, if there is no pair possible with all the elements in a list then I should return False if the pair is possible with all the same elements in a list then I want to return true.

For example:

1. `[1,2,1,2]` then I want to return true
2. `[1,2,2,3]` then I want to return false as there is no pair of 1 and 3.
3. `[4,4,4]` then I want to return false as there is no possible pair with the left element 4.

I tried with the following code but I am not getting the proper output that I am expecting, so please help me, thanks.

```py
def pair(A):
    count =0 
    A.sort()
    if len(A)%2!=0:
        return False
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
          if A[i] == A[i+1]:
             count = count+1
             i=i+1
          else:
             return False
    if count==len(A)/2:
       return True
    
    
A=[1,2,1,2]
print(pair(A))
```

Output:
False

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.

But It should be true.

Answer (score 1):

You should skip the second element of your pair, you can achieve this by using `range(0, len(A), 2) = [0,2,4,...]`

```py
def pair(A):
    A.sort()
    if len(A)%2!=0:
        return False
    for i in range(0,len(A), 2):
        if A[i] != A[i+1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Forgot to remove the `count =0`. And shorter version: `A.sort(); return A[::2] == A[1::2]` (but I like that you stayed close to the OP's).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it worked well now… cheer..

Comment: @KellyBundy can you please tell me what’s wrong in my code? I have incremented the “i “ by 2 if the fst element and second element are same.. you

Comment: In the next iteration it will take the next element from the range, it is not doing i+=1, like you would do in other languages like C.

Comment: @Bob Oh ok understood! thanks. But i was in the impression that i am incrementing the i value with i=i+1.

Comment: Yes, what you are doing is `i = 0`, `i = i + 1` (i = 1 in the end of first iteration), second iteration `i=1`, `i = i + 1`, every time you assign `i` to a constant to start the new iteration, it discards the value at the end of the previous iteration.